# how can I express a circle in the complex plane that passes through a particular real number (say $-1$)

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to show that a möbius transformation maps any circle that passes through $-1$ to a line, but I have no idea how express such a broad category of circle in polar form, or any form for that matter.

The möbius transformation in question is $f(z) = \frac{z - 1}{iz + i}$

Comment: A Möbius transformation transforms circles into circles (with lines being taken a limiting circle), so all you need to show is that $f(z)$ is not bounded for $z$ in the circle. In this particular case, $|f(-1)| = \infty$, so you know that any circle that passes through $-1$ is mapped to a line.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Suppose you want a circle that passes through the point $a+ib$.Let us say the center of such a circle is $p+iq$. Then 
$$|z-(p+iq)|=|(a-p)+i(b-q)|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A line is a circle on the Riemann sphere (the complex numbers with $\infty$ adjoined) that passes through $\infty$.  A Möbius transformation maps a circle to a line iff it maps some point on that circle to $\infty$.